# visual paradigm - background

Tags: export, jpeg, visual-paradigm

I want to export my diagram as image. I get the diagram with text (on background) "Visual Paradigm Professional Edition". I don't want it. I want only to get alone diagram with white background. Let me know how can I change it.

Answer (score 1):

The exported image will be watermark free as long as you running the software with paid license, either in [perpetual](https://www.visual-paradigm.com/shop/vp.jsp?license=perpetual) or [monthly subscription](https://www.visual-paradigm.com/shop/vp.jsp) type.